# Alternate to LISTAGG function in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, string-aggregation

I using LISTAGG function to convert row values into one single column but facing below error. When searched, when the result rows exceeds more than 65535 [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html]. My result set is more 100000 so I get the exception below. What is the alternate to this function? How can I achieve my use case in redshift. Please help.

````
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit
  code:      8001
  context:   LISTAGG limit: 65535
  process:   query18_863_20899937 [pid=66066]```


**My Use Case**
From:

ID     dates
00     date00
01     date00
00     date01
00     date02
00     date03
01     date01


**To: [Using LISTAGG function]**
ID   dates
00   date00,date01,date02,date03
01   date00,date01

Thanks.
````

Comment: I was able to fix the problem. The problem is not when number of rows is more than 65535 it is when the varchar size of the column it tries to aggregate exceeds 65535

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to show the query (or the key parts of it) that you are running but I think I can suggest a direction.  LISTAGG() has a "WITHIN GROUP" option and is documented at the link you mention in your post.

Listagg() within group will aggregate the text column only for the values in the group defined in the "GROUP BY" clause.  So to meet your deesired output you should be able to do something like:

```
select ID, listagg(dates) within group as dates
from <table>
group by ID;
```

The same listagg() limit will exist - it is just that now it is applied to each "group by" group.  If this still produces a text string that is too long you will need to break things into more groups.  When this happens I will calculate a "subpart" column which increments for every 1,000 rows in the group.  This way I can ensure that no group will produce more than 1,000 rows for listagg() to consume.

Comment: Thanks Bill Weiner. I used the same query as above.